# Key "image" for array with keys "id, title, artext, createdat, updatedat, position, status" does not exist

Tags: key, symfony5

I'm working on Symfony 5.4, and have the following bugg

```
Key "image" for array with keys "id, title, status" does not exist.
```

Then I have two tables: **Image** and **Article** and need to post and arraw of Article, each article with his image.

**Article Repository**

```
public function findbyLast() {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb->andWhere('a.status = 1');
    $qb->orderBy('a.id', 'DESC');
    $qb->setMaxResults( 10 );
    return  $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

**Article Controller**

```
#[Route('/articles', name: 'articles')]
public function articles(ArticleRepository $articles): Response
{
    return $this->render('main/articles.html.twig', [
        'articles' => $articles->findbyLast() ,
    ]);
}
```

**View on Twig**

```
{% for x in articles %}
<a href="{{ path('app_article_show', {'id': x.id}) }}">
<h4>{{ x.title }}</h4>
{% if x.image %}
    <img src="{{ asset('images/articles/'~x.image )}}" alt="{{ x.image.name }}" class="img-fluid row">
{% endif %}
```

{% endfor %}

I'v struggled on it, and don't know how to manage my repository to join and have that missing key.

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

bugg resolved. I didn't make the difference between

> getResult and getArrayResult in the repository. Get Result is rendering a list of objects and the other an array.